# Azure data factory - Append static header to each file available in blob container

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I would like to append static header to the each file(.txt) available in blob storage container, how can I handle this task in azure data factory?
Static header is stored in separate text file in the same blob storage container
Example:
I/P Header, File1 , File2 ,File3
O/P Header File1, Header File2, Header File3

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Step:

1.create a variable used to put some configuration data, type is array

```
[{"contant_name":"PID.txt","head_name":"Header.txt","sink_filename":"total.txt"}]
```

[image]

2.create For Each activity
[image]

3.create data flow inside For Each activity and new a parameter
[image]

[image]

4.create header dataset and content dataset
[image]

[image]

5.create Union activity in data flow
[image]

6.create a sink dataset and make setting of sink like this

[image]

[image]

[image]